# I cannot do anything to dynamically added content within window load resize function

Tags: jquery

[working demo without window load resize](http://jsfiddle.net/urGcv/)

But the same code within the load resize function is not working properly.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){

$('div').wrapAll('<div class="cc" />');
$('.cc div').wrap('<div class="group" />');

var groupLength = $('.cc .group').length;
    var groups = $('.cc .group');
    if(groupLength == 2){
        groups.css('width','50%');
    } else if(groupLength == 3){
        groups.css('width','33.33%');
    } else {
        groups.css('width','10%');
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urGcv/1/)

---

You may say it's working when resizing. But obviously it's not working on load, why? So, there might be a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger `resize()` on page load since `jsFiddle` has wrapped your code inside `$(window).load(function() {...});` by default:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){

$('div').wrapAll('<div class="cc" />');
$('.cc div').wrap('<div class="group" />');

var groupLength = $('.cc .group').length;
    var groups = $('.cc .group');
    if(groupLength == 2){
        groups.css('width','50%');
    } else if(groupLength == 3){
        groups.css('width','33.33%');
    } else {
        groups.css('width','10%');
    }
}).resize(); // <-- Here
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urGcv/2/)**

Comment: There is no need to trigger the event manually... just change the wrapper using the second drop down in the left panel

Comment: @ArunPJohny What can I do for my site? that's not with fiddle?

Comment: @C-link did you place the code in another wrapper function? if so remove it

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm using external js file.

Answer (score 0):

It is because by default the fiddle adds the script in a window.load handler so by the time your script is executed the window.load event is already fired so your handler will not get executed again.

In the second dropdown in the left panel select `No Wrap`

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {

    $('div').wrapAll('<div class="cc" />');
    $('.cc div').wrap('<div class="group" />');

    var groupLength = $('.cc .group').length;
    var groups = $('.cc .group');
    if (groupLength == 2) {
        groups.css('width', '50%');
    } else if (groupLength == 3) {
        groups.css('width', '33.33%');
    } else {
        groups.css('width', '10%');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uPsyk/)

The `window.load` event does not work like `document.ready` handler which will call the handler method even if the event is already triggered.